# Accessing a function variable without calling the function

Tags: python, json, pandas, function

**Background -**
I am a beginner, who is writing their first serious program; an API call is made, which returns a response that I save as a `.json` file, and dataframe (`df`) before doing some math and transformation and saving as a new dataframe called `exceptions_df`. Finally, I am looking to write both `df` and `exceptions_df` to a `.xlsx` file (`def xlsx_writer()`).

**Problem -**
`def xlsx_writer():` writes the `exception_df` to a `.xlsx` file no problem. However, I would also like it to write `df` to the same file.

Whilst I can access the `df` variable by using `df = def ownership_qc()`, that function also calls other functions (`df = unpack_response()`), which itself, calls another function named `api_response = response_writer())`. Can you see my problem? My code would unnecessarily be repeating itself (i.e., calling related functions again) by using this method. My current code does this and 'works', however it seems very silly to be repeating code; and it's ultra slow.

**Relevant functions -** 
**`def xlsx_writer`** - this is the function I would like to utilize `df` in. It currently does that through `df = ownership_qc()`, however it's slow, based on the above description:

```
def xlsx_writer():
    exceptions_df = ownership_exceptions()
#   This is where I call df and cause the a chain reaction of ownership_qc() calling function it requires and so forth.
    df = ownership_qc()
    
    timestr = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M")
    filename = 'ownership_exceptions_'+timestr
    
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(filename+'.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
    exceptions_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Ownership Exceptions Report', startrow=1, header=False, index=False)
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Raw Extract', startrow=1, header=False, index=False)
    workbook = writer.book
    worksheet = writer.sheets['Ownership Exceptions Report']
    (max_row, max_col) = exceptions_df.shape
    column_settings = [{'header': column} for column in exceptions_df.columns]
    worksheet.add_table(0, 0, max_row, max_col - 1, {'columns': column_settings})
    worksheet.set_column(0, max_col - 1, 12)
xlsx_writer()
```

**`def ownership_exceptions():`** -
This is the function I call in `def xlsx_writer()` to access `df`. The problem is that this function calls another function, and starts the chain reaction:

```
# This is the function I am calling to acces `df`, however this function calls another function.
def ownership_exceptions():
    df = ownership_qc()
    df = df[(df['Entity ID %'] != 1.000000) & (df['Account # %'] != 1.000000)]
    df.drop(df.index[df['Entity ID %'] == '1'], inplace=True)
    exceptions_df = df.drop(['Model Type', 'Valuation (USD)', 'Top Level Legal Entity', 'Financial Service', 'Account Close Date'], axis=1)
    return df
```

**My thoughts**

- Is there a way to access `df` without having it's function (`def ownership_exceptions`) called and thus all other related functions called?
- Should I simply create a new function that loads the API response (.json) back into a dataframe and access that way?

Comment: Change your code to have `ownership_exceptions` take `df` as a parameter, so you can pass it in instead of having it reload everything from scratch.

Comment: `ownership_exceptions` returns `df`, not `exceptions_df` - is that intentional?

Comment: Sorry - typo, should return exceptions_df.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably make `ownership_exceptions` return (a tuple of) two values: `exception_df` and `df`. That way, you don't need to call `ownership_qc` twice.

Update your `ownership_exceptions` a bit, to process `exceptions_df` instead of `df`:

```
def ownership_exceptions():
    df = ownership_qc()
    exceptions_df = df[(df['Entity ID %'] != 1.000000) & (df['Account # %'] != 1.000000)]
    exceptions_df = df[df['Entity ID %'] != '1']
    exceptions_df = df.drop(['Model Type', 'Valuation (USD)', 'Top Level Legal Entity', 'Financial Service', 'Account Close Date'], axis=1)
    return exceptions_df, df  # <---- Notice two values are being returned here
```

And change your `xlsx_writer` function to only call `ownership_exceptions`:

```
def xlsx_writer():
    exceptions_df, df = ownership_exceptions()
    
    # now use exceptions_df and df...
```

Comment: Thank you for your input - unfortunately this still seems to call the functions again.

Comment: So `ownership_qc` is being called multiple times?'